# Li passando da linha

Tags: html, css

Coloquei 5 `li` com uma imagem para cada link `a` dentro da `Li`. Após isso, eu coloquei um `:hover` na `Li` para que a imagem trocasse ao passar o mouse por cima, mas acontece que o `width` esta `100%`, e não posso troca-lo porque o meu `div` não ficaria centralizado no caso.

Alguem tem uma solução?

Exemplificando: o `width` do botão é de `184px` e o `width` do `hover` ficou em `100%`(toda a pagina), segue imagem e código:

```css
//Ranking
#ranking{
  width:100%;
  margin-top:1155px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left:-388px;
}

#ranking ul{
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  list-style: none;
}

#ranking ul li {
  width:100%;
  background:url(../imagens/button.png) no-repeat center;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0px;
}

#ranking ul li a{
  height:27px;
  width:184px;
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#E4E4E4;
}

#ranking li a:hover{
}

#ranking ul li:hover{
  background:url(../imagens/buttonhover.png) center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!-- Index.php -->

<div id="ranking">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Top PvP</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Top PK</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Top Clan</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Top Online</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Boss Online</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Execute esse código que você disponibilizou para nós e você verá que não é possível entender a sua pergunta.

Comment: Cristian, [edit] sua pergunta, e coloque as imagens em servidor na internet, e coloque a URL das imagens no seu CSS.

Comment: Amigo não está muito claro sua pergunta, você diz que no hover a imagem passa do tamanho da div?